# Нужно исправить ошибки в коде Pascal

Tags: pascal

При вводе данных m и n, ничего не происходит.

```
const
   maxn = 20; maxm = 20;
var
   n, m, i, j, max, imax, jmax, min, imin, jmin: Integer;
   b: array[1..maxn, 1..maxm] of Integer;
begin
   write('n = '); readln(n);
   write('m = '); readln(m);
   for i:= 1 to n do
      for j:= 1 to m do
         read(b[i, j]);
   imax:= 1; jmax:= 1; max:= b[imax, jmax];
   imin:= 1; jmin:= 1; min:= b[imin, jmin];
   for i:= 1 to n do
      for j:= 1 to m do
      begin
         if max < b[i, j] then
         begin
            imax:= i; jmax:= j; max:= b[imax, jmax];
         end;
         if min > b[i, j] then
         begin
            imin:= i; jmin:= j; min:= b[imin, jmin];
         end;
      end;
   writeln('Разность наибольшего и наименьшего элемента: ', max-min);
   writeln('Индексы наибольшего элемента: i = ', imax, ' j = ', jmax);
   writeln('Индексы наименьшего элемента: i = ', imin, ' j = ', jmin);
   Readln;
end.
```

Comment: а что должно происходить-то? у меня все работает

Answer (score 2):

Ничего исправлять не надо.

Происходит ожидание ввода: `read(b[i, j]);`

Пока пользователь не заполнит n*m значений, программа будет тихо ждать.